# How to Change this Burned Out Light Bulb

Tags: lighting

Does anyone know how to change this strange [image]light bulb in this “recessed” light fixture? I tried rotating the bulb counterclockwise but it doesn’t turn/unscrew. The bulb can be pushed up but I can’t get a grip around the perimeter to see if it will pull down. The ring immediately surrounding it can pivot to change the angle of the light but also does NOT rotate. Help!

Answer (score 3):

If it's a GU10 base or similar it's like a bayonet fitting. Push in then twist (usually anticlockwise) and it should pop out.

https://www.lightbulbs-direct.com/article/gu10-lightbulb-guide/

To grip the bulb use a sucker or removal tool, eg

https://www.screwfix.com/p/wolfcraft-wfc-5499000-gu10-lamp-removal-tool/6084k

Comment: Owain, Thanks so much for this info and the links. With your help, I was able to change the bulb!

Answer (score 2):

All, this fixture was a recessed light fixture and required a counterclockwise rotation of the entire fixture. Once the fixture was loose/hanging by the wires, the guts of the light assembly could be seen. There was a clip locking the bulb in place which was released from the bulb using a small screwdriver. The GU10 bulb was removed from behind the face/trim ring using a counterclockwise rotation and could then be replaced. (Wish I took a picture but was just so glad it was fixed that I reassembled and reinstalled.)

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to get yourself a plastic one 1 inch drywall blade and slide it between the ceiling and the edge of the fixture. Once inside lift up all the way around and the fixture will pop out.